# Adobe AIR custom chrome L-shape

Tags: air

I want to create an Adobe AIR application that is L-shaped so that another application can fit in the open area of the screen.  In other words, I would like an AIR app to surround another application on 2 sides (left and bottom).  Is this possible? And if I do this, will the AIR app cover the other application with a transparency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty space will allow another application to reside there without having a layer over it

Answer (score 0):

To have a transparent background:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/creating_transparent_window.html

Adapt you descriptor file, then make 2 canvas elements with a backgroundColor and backgroundAlpha (which form you L-shape).

If the Air App covers the other application with a transparent layer: try building the Air App first and then the application that has to reside "in" it.